# Can we use parse.facebookutils to retrieve friend list from facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am new to parse.com. And my aim is to retrieve the friendlist from facebook and store it into my database. I couldn't find the relevant method in parse.facebookutils api. Wondering if there is some another way to do it. Can anyone provide me an easy example to demonstrate the retrieval ? I want to do it in javascript for a iOS mobile application as a backend process. I hope the information is sufficient. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: what is stopping you ?

Comment: basically i am not sure if i need to compulsorily use parse.FacebookUtils or i can directly use fb.api and start using the defined methods ?

Comment: why not try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Parse then use FacebookUtils to manage Login, Logout and Facebook user sessions. Parse makes it very easy as it internally uses Facebook SDK so we don't have to use it again. :)

```
Can we use parse.facebookutils to retrieve friend list from facebook?
```

Yes we can, but you dont directly use FacebookUtils class for this. You will have to follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends) to get the Friend List.

[Here's](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial/tree/master/IntegratingFacebookTutorial-Android) how FacebookUtils does the authentication part and rest is pure Facebook SDK.

Comment: Also, as a side note, if your app uses v2.0+ of the Graph API (which it will if it has been created on or after April 30th 2014), /me/friends will only return a list of friends that already use your app.